# Deploy single RDL file SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, web-deployment, business-intelligence

I need to modify the SQL script on the existing SSRS RDL file on my client machine.
So I have opened the existing RDL file on notepad and edited the script. Then saved the file as “.RDL” file. Then I checked the report on the browser and I could see the result is not reflected on the report.

So I have checked this on my local machine by opening the RDL file on the visual studio business intelligence tool and deployed the project. I could find the change is reflected on the report.

I want to know how can I deploy only the single file on to the client machine. Also I could not see the the solution file, bin folder and data source of the RDL file on client machine. Can any one help me to deploy the the single file on client machine?

Comment: The RDL file you edit on the client machine isn't the report to edit, as the server runs from its own collection of reports in a database, which is what the deploy does.. So you need to deploy to your client machine's report server. As the answer so far says, you can do this within Report manager and upload/replace the individual report with your changed file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean an SSRS Server when you say 'client machine'....

From the SSRS Web Portal (in SQL 2016) or the SSRS Report Manager in earlier versions. Navigate to the report and (again depending on version) go to properties/manage.

You will see options to download (which will download the rdl file ready to edit) and upload/replace which will allow you to upload the rdl directly back to the server.

These instruction may not be perfect, I'm doing this from memory but it should point you in the right direction.

The other option of course is to create a Reporting Services project in Visual Studio and deploy from there.